# FlexboxLayout count lines

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I need to add views programmatically to FlexboxLayout and for each view added check if it created a new row or not.

How can I get Row count?

Tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            flexboxlayout.add(createView(this.getContext(), i));

            //log
            Log.e("position: " + i + " ; row count -> " + flexboxlayout.getFlexLines().size());
}
```

getFlexLines method does not always return the expected Line count.

Comment: may be you can do total height of parent/ height of child and round it off

Comment: Have you tried `getFlexLinesInternal().size()`?